# Would hardly have been notable

Tags: tense

Can anyone explain to me how to use the phrase ***would hardly have been***?

I came across this phrase in an article in The Atlantic titled "The Far Right Wants to Gut the EU, Not Kill It."

The writer wrote:

> A few years ago, the party membership's decision to include a so-called Dexit in its 2019 platform ... **would hardly have been notable**."

Why not simply use ***was hardly notable***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that it didn't happen. "A few years ago, they did not include Dexit in the party's platform.  But if they had done, it would have been barely notable."

Comment: That's a clear explanation. Another thing about the meaning of the sentence (the word "hardly" is so confusing). It means if the far-right politicians did include the Dexit in their platform, people would not/hardly have noticed, Right? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. (NB: I corrected my ungrammatical "would not have been barely", apologies.)